# Can't Get TableLayout to Programatically Be Created

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, tablelayout

I've created what I want in xml but I need to do it programatically and I can't get it to work. It's a table layout with one row. In that row there is two more table layouts. The first of which has one row containing a picture and the second table layout has two rows containing two textviews and a picture. Is there some kind of xml to java converter? I've tried to write the code now for a couple of hours and can't get the layouts to work. I'd post a picture but I need 10 rep points first. The whole xml file is in a linear layout if it helps.

```
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablemain"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:weightSum="100" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Tableout2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:maxHeight="100dp"
                            android:maxWidth="100dp"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/unknown" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Tableout3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="100"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="100" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="50"
                        android:background="@drawable/border" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Judgename"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:padding="7dp"
                            android:text="Name"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tablerowctroom"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="50"
                        android:background="@drawable/border"
                        android:weightSum="100" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Courtroom"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="70"
                            android:padding="7dp"
                            android:text="Room"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="30"
                            android:src="@drawable/umid" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

This is the new code I'm trying to use based on Nathan Walter's advice. However, It'll set the first set text but the rest are just the default value. Although the layout looks right. How can I set the textfields for each individual view when the method is called.

```
public void Display(String name, String ctroom) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);

    view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tablebutton, null);
    parent.addView(view);
    TextView jn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.JudgenameCourts);
    jn.setText(name);

    TextView ct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Courtroomnew);
    ct.setText(ctroom);

    view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tablebutton, null);
    parent.addView(view);

    jn.setText("Name1");

    ct.setText("Courtroom1");

}
```

Comment: If you've successfully created it in XML, why do you want to do it programmatically?

Comment: I need to make several rows from an array. Its for a directory and so the number of people could change.

Comment: Your best option then is probably to inflate multiple copies of your XML layout, initialize your `TextView`s and `ImageView`s with the appropriate data, and then add those manually to a `ViewGroup`.

Comment: I've never used ViewGroup before. Do you have an example of what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, `ViewGroup` is the parent class of classes like `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`. In this case, since you're probably trying to create a list? You would add these views to a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you but how do you set the same textview to be different each time you load the xml?

Comment: I'll post some pseudocode as an anwer.

Comment: Wait, have you considered using a ListAdapter for this? From the sound of it, you're trying to create a list of people from an array, which is exactly what an adapter is for.

Comment: In your code, you never update the references for `jn` and `ct` when you inflate the layout the second time. So immediately after you set the name and ctroom passed into the function, you set them back to "Name1" and "Courtroom1".

Comment: How can I change the reference if the id in the xml file always the same? How can I initiate new textview's and place them where the current textview in the xml is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code you want looks something like this. Let me know if it makes sense.

```
// Create an array of things to create views from.
// You will probably be getting your array from somewhere else
YourObjectHere[] things = new YourObjectHere[2];
things[0] = new YourObjectHere();
things[1] = new YourObjectHere();

// Get a reference to a LinearLayout to hold your views
LinearLayout list = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list);

// Loop through your list of objects
for(int i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {

    // Inflate an instance of your layout
    View listItem = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, null);

    // Set the TextViews to the appropriate things
    ((TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(things[i].getName());
    ((TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.type)).setText(things[i].getType());

    // Add the inflated view to the list
    item.addView(child);
}
```